# How do I load my javascript file inside my partial view that is nested inside a view? MVC5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two custom made javascript files (viewJscript.js, and partialJscript.js). Inside the view i simply put:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/viewJscript.js"></script>
```

And this works just fine. Now I am trying to do the same in my partial view which is nested inside the view:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/partialJscript.js"></script>
```

And it doesnt work. **So what should I do in order to load my partialJscript.js inside my partial view?**

I forgot to mention that the partial view is dynamic and is opened upon a button click from the view

**EDIT** Here is my code inside the partialJscript.js file:

```
$(function () {
        var divSensorNames = $("#sensorNames");
        $('.webgrid2-table th:first-child,  .webgrid2-table td:first-child').hide();

        $('.webgrid2-table th:nth-child(2),  .webgrid2-table td:nth-child(2)').hide();

        $('.webgrid2-table th:nth-child(3),  .webgrid2-table td:nth-child(3)').hide();

        $('#AddNewSensor').on('click', function () {
            $('#sensorList').load('@Url.Action("ChooseSensorList", "PredefinedViews")');
        });

        $('.editSensorMode').on("click", function () {
            var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
            //var SensorID = tr.find("#SensorID").html();
            var PredefinedViewItemID = tr.find("#PredefineViewsItemID").html();
            var urlEditModes = "@Url.Action("EditSensorMode", "PredefinedViews", new { pviId = "PredefinedViewItemID" })";
            //urlEditModes = urlEditModes.replace("SensorID", SensorID);
            urlEditModes = urlEditModes.replace("PredefinedViewItemID", PredefinedViewItemID);
            $('#sensorList').load(urlEditModes);
        });

        $(".sensor-delete-table").on("click", function () {

            var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
            var PredefineViewsItemID = tr.find("#PredefineViewsItemID").html();
            var PredefineViewID = tr.find("#PredefineViewID").html();
            var amount = parseInt($("[data-id='" + PredefineViewID + "']").text());
            //amount = amount + anyNumber; This also works!
            //var rowCountBefore = $('.webgrid2-table tr').length;

            var flag = confirm('@Html.Localize("deleteCheck")');
            var urlShowNewSensors = "@Url.Action("ShowSensorNames", "PredefinedViews", new { predefinedViewID = "PredefineViewID" })";
            urlShowNewSensors = urlShowNewSensors.replace("PredefineViewID", PredefineViewID);
            if (PredefineViewID != "" && flag) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteSensor", "PredefinedViews")',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ pviID: PredefineViewsItemID, pID: PredefineViewID }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    complete: function (result) {

                        var urlShowSensors = "@Url.Action("ShowSensorNames", "PredefinedViews", new { predefinedViewID = "PredefID" })";
                        urlShowSensors = urlShowSensors.replace("PredefID", PredefineViewID);
                        $(divSensorNames).load(urlShowSensors);

                        amount--;
                        $("[data-id='" + PredefineViewID + "']").text(amount.toString());
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is this loaded after the DOM has loaded?

Comment: no, the partial loaded after a certain button click in the view

Comment: So it's rendered as an additional part of the page? After the main page has loaded?
What I'm trying to say is if the js is loaded after the main page. Then the js needs to be loaded in as the DOM has already loaded.

Comment: Note: Idon't think you need to load jquery twice.

Comment: @LiamSorsby Yes, it is rendered as an aditional part of the page. I tried loading both scripts in the view but it got me nowhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, you're using AJAX to bring in the HTML of the partial view. For security reasons, browsers do not allow scripts tags from dynamically-inserted HTML to be run. You'll either have to include the script in your main view, or load the script dynamically via JavaScript in your AJAX callback. You can do this with something like Require.js or Modernizr.load.

Comment: I tried to include the script in my main view and it got me nowhere.  So how do I do the second thing you suggested?

Comment: What do you mean it got you nowhere? You said it worked previously when you had the scripts on the main view. Perhaps, if it doesn't work anymore it's because your script is interacting with the DOM before you've actually inserted the partial view. Everything that should be done on anything in the partial view should happen in the AJAX callback.

Comment: What I mean is when I try and put both viewJscript.js AND partialJscript.js inside the view it doesnt work. Nothing I do makes the partial view render its script. Unless I copy paste the contents of partialJscript.js inside of the partial view, but I hear that that is bad pratcise?

Comment: Again, check what you're doing in partialJscript.js. If you're interacting with anything in your partial view directly, it's not going to work, regardless. AJAX is async, so you have to work with its results in the callback method. You can wrap your partialJscript.js code in a function, and then call that function in the AJAX callback.

Comment: 1. To open the partial view I am using $(#myDiv).load(url); and not ajax, so how do i do the ajax call back after that?
2. even if i can do that, how do i wrap the partialJscript.js in a function?

Comment: 1. `$.load` *is* AJAX. It's just a convenience method that jQuery provides, and it has a callback parameter. See: http://api.jquery.com/load/. 2. I'm talking about the code *inside* that file. You haven't posted that code, so I can't give you any guidance other than whatever code inside that file that interacts with your partial view HTML needs to be wrapped in a function that can then be called inside your callback function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67337/discussion-between-vrankela-and-chris-pratt).